# I tried deploying my react application but after npm run deploy finishes running it does not appear on the github pages

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginer in react and i tried deploying a built app but it keeps saying this and when I visit the page it says site not found

```
File sizes after gzip:

  46.96 kB  build\static\js\main.af048963.js
  1.11 kB   build\static\css\main.37b3eb86.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /react-gh-pages.github.io/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at /react-gh-pages.github.io/ , run:

  npm run deploy

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> profile@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

Published
```